# Spring security: Session is invalidated when user isn't authenticated

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

Whenever I run my web application and I go to the default page, I get a `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` user inside my authorities which is expected. However, when I go idle, the session times out which causes my `invalid-session-url` to be triggered. Is there anyway to exclude unauthenticated users from the session timeout?

EDIT: The easiest way I found is by setting an `InvalidSessionStrategy`. Problem is, I don't know how to. I don't really need to create my own implementation of `SessionManagementFilter`. What I want is control of how the application will handle `invalid-session-url`. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Having a session is a good practice even for un-authenticated users. Implement your invalid-session-url in a way that it checks for authentication before redirecting. If the user is not authenticated, redirect to a session-idle-timeout page.

Comment: Whenever the application triggers the invalid-session-url, I lose all the authorities I previously had and all I get is ROLE_ANONYMOUS.

Comment: @MiguelPortugal That's what's supposed to happen. If the user wasn't authenticated, he wouldn't have had any authorities anyway, surely?

Comment: Yes I know, but if ever I was authenticated -- I had, for instance, a role called ROLE_USER -- it disappears once it reaches the invalid-session-url. Since the session was already invalidated by <session-management>, all the roles I previously had disappeared because apparently Spring clears everything.

Comment: What do you mean by Spring clears everything? Where are you storing your roles? And what exactly are you doing while invalidating the session?

Comment: From what I've observed, whenever an invalid session is detected by Spring, the authorities stored inside the Authentication object are all removed and replaced by the default 'ROLE_ANONYMOUS'. Basically, a new session is instantly created.

What I want to do is essentially have multiple 'invalid-session-url's depending on the roles (authorities) stored in the Authentication object.

ROLE_ANONYMOUS should redirect to anonymous-session-expired
ROLE_** should redirect to session-expired

Comment: If you are redirecting to a different URL, there is no way you can keep your Auth object. The easier way to manage that will be, invalidate the session, but don't redirect to any URL.